# Create file in Windows Explorer locking FileTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream, ssms, filetable

I just got started using FileTables in SQL Server 2012. I have set everything up on a remote server and got things rolling without any issues. Non-transactional file inserts etc worked absolutely fine.

However, when I attempted to create a new Text-file in the FileTable share directory from Windows Explorer (right-click -> New -> Text Document), it totally froze. Now when I execute queries at the FileTable, the queries just freeze and I get no response. So I figured that my non-transactional insert from the file system had put a lock on the FileTable.

Anyhow, this is what I've tried so far (without success):

- Kill ongoing filestream handles (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492061.aspx#BasicsKilling) with no results. The executions just freeze.

  ```
  -- Kill all handles on database
  EXEC sp_kill_filestream_non_transacted_handles;
  GO

  -- Kill handles on filetable
  EXEC sp_kill_filestream_non_transacted_handles @table_name = 'dbo.MyFileTable';
  GO

  -- Kill single handle
  EXEC sp_kill_filestream_non_transacted_handles @handle_id = <handle id>;
  GO
  ```
- Take database offline. This results in the error message:

  ```
  Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
  ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'FOO'. Try again later.
  ```
- Drop database. This results in the error message:

  ```
  Msg 3702, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
  Cannot drop database "FOO" because it is currently in use.
  ```
- Kill ongoing sessions(?) on my Database:

  ```
  EXEC sp_who2
  KILL <SPID>
  ```

As mentioned, I'm unable to interract both Transactionally and Non-transactionally with my FileTable. As you can see, I can't even drop my own Database.

Any suggestions in what may have caused this? Should I be careful using FileTables? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by restarting the SQL Server instance. This was the last resort though, since it's a remote instance which is used by my company.

I believe that this problem was caused by the fact that i **created** a file directly in my FileTable directory. In the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492083.aspx#HowToLoadNew) it is stated the following:

> The methods that you can use to load files into a FileTable include
>   the following:
>
> - **Drag and drop** files from the source folders to the new FileTable folder in Windows Explorer.
> - Use command line options such as **MOVE, COPY, XCOPY, or ROBOCOPY** from the command prompt or in a batch
>     file or script.
> - Write a custom application in C# or Visual Basic.NET that uses methods from the System.IO namespace to **move or copy** the files.

However, it is not stated that **creating files** may cause problems. Unfortunately, it did in my case. Hopefully this answer can help people with similar issues in the future.